# Why and when should Read/Write Splitting in MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am a fresher for database tuning, I am trying to learning improve my PostgreSQL database performance, So I search lots of articles in google

There are many advices are Read/Write Splitting for MySQL, because of read will affect write.

But when I reading PostgreSQL official documentation that said PostgreSQL using snapshot as MVCC(mean each SQL statement sees a snapshot of data), This approach seems read is not affect write, So is it mean PostgreSQL do not need Read/Write Splitting?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, no need to split them. Get used to EXPLAIN and how to use it, that's one of the most important parts in performance tuning.

Comment: MVCC doesn't mean that read won't be affected if write is in progress. MySQL also uses MVCC, it's not Postgres-only. Read can always affect writes. There are so many cases where you can have fast reads, fast writes, it all depends on the concurrency, load, hardware, how much of your data is in RAM for faster access, how many I/Os you have at your disposal etc. You split reads and writes when you have a lot of requests handled by your database. Then you dedicate read-only nodes to reading and write-only that replicates to others. I believe you're not at the stage where you need this.

Answer (score 1):

With a streaming replication scenario, you can certainly split reads and writes to scale horizontally.

Note that there can be a small delay between the time when a transaction commits at the primary and the time when a query at the standby will return the new result, even if you use synchronous streaming replication.

I'd say that you should consider other performance tuning measures first.